# Getting gcal4ruby gem to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-plugins, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to create a RoR web application that allows people to connect to their accounts to google calendar.

I found a gem called gcal4ruby that seemed to do the right things based on looking at sample code and its documentation.

I ran gem install and the cmd claimed the installation was ok.

However, when I added the gem to my gemfile then try to run the server again I get:
Could not find 'gcal4ruby (= 0.0.5, runtime)' in any of the gem sources
Try running 'bundle install'.

Then I tried bundle install which basically gets me the message above and a line:
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Could not find 'gcal4ruby (= 0.0.5, runtime)' in any of the gem sources

Yet when I type in "gem list -d g", gcal4ruby (0.5.5) appears on the list.
I've tried adding in requires and includes but that just gets me uninitialized constant errors.

Other details that may be relevant:
ruby 1.8.7
rails 3.0.1

gem check --alien returns:
mysql-2.8.1-x86-mingw32 has 1 problems
 .require_paths:
  Extra file
*Note: This doesn't seem to negatively impact me when I'm doing anything though.

If possible, please supply tutorials/sites with samples of working code.

Cheers,
Zigu

Answer (score 0):

Could you post your gemfile please?

I'm guessing your Gemfile reads

```
gem 'gcal4ruby', '0.0.5'
```

which means it will only look for that specific verison. So there are two ways to fix this.

1. Change it to minimum version syntax

   gem 'gcal4ruby', '>= 0.0.5'
2. Change to correct specific gem version

   gem 'gcal4ruby', '0.5.5'

Hope that helps