# Installing gems tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, installation

Is there anywhere that there are step by step instructions on how to install gems?

My google-fu is weak and those that I could find did not resolve my error.

My errors are detailed here:
[Getting gcal4ruby gem to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182265/getting-gcal4ruby-gem-to-work)

Basically my error sums up as:
gem installs properly and is detectable by,
but whenever I try to reference it in my application it just says:
Could not find 'gcal4ruby (= 0.0.5, runtime)' in any of the gem sources Try running 'bundle install'.

(* I tried bundle install -> no help *)

Comment: Splitting your question into two makes it kind of difficult for people to get the answers they seek. If you could move the errors into this question it'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error states:

```
 Could not find 'gcal4ruby (= 0.0.5, runtime)' in any of the gem sources Try running 'bundle install'.
```

It's looking for `0.0.5` of gcal4ruby, which you don't have installed, rather you're saying yourself that the `gem list -d` shows:

```
 gcal4ruby (0.5.5)
```

Which is *not* the correct version. I would recommend attempting to discover what's trying to require this older version of `gcal4ruby`. I think it's in your `Gemfile`, but I have been known to be wrong occasionally.

If this answer doesn't solve your question, then please attach the errors you're getting and your `Gemfile` to your question.

Answer (score 0):

As a guess, you are using rails 3? Rails 3 uses a project called bundler for dependencies, so instead of installing the gem in your system ruby, add `gem 'gcal4ruby` to the `Gemfile` in the root of your app. after that, a `bundle install` will install the gem locally into your app.

Bundler means that rails 3 apps have their gems completely isolated from the system gems. Even if the gem is installed in the system, it will not be accessible in the app.